# Soundcloud to CSV File

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, csv, http

This program [connects to Soundcloud](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide) and turns the supplied username into a CSV file with the user's like list. The code accomplishes this although it looks rather messy and was wondering what I could change to improve it.

```
import soundcloud
import urllib.request
import json
import requests

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id="********************************")


def get_username():
    """
    Asks user for their Soundcloud username.
    """
    username = input("Please enter your Soundcloud username: ")
    user_id = (valid_username(username))
    print(user_id)


def valid_username(username):
    """
    Checks if supplied username is valid.
    """
    global user
    try:
        user = client.get("/resolve", url="http://soundcloud.com/{}/".format(username))
        user_info(user.id)
    except requests.HTTPError:  # Runs if account cannot be found.
        print("The username you entered is invalid, please try again")
        get_username()


def user_info(user_id):
    """
    Retrieves the users information from their user ID
    and prints the number of tracks they have liked.
    """
    global number_of_user_likes
    retrieve = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{}.json?consumer_key="
                                      "********************************".format(user_id)).read()
    decode_user_info = json.loads(retrieve.decode())
    number_of_user_likes = decode_user_info['public_favorites_count']
    username = decode_user_info['username']
    print("You have liked a total of {} tracks".format(number_of_user_likes))
    save_likes(username)


def save_likes(username):
    """
    Creates a CSV file with headers and then saves the users likes to the CSV file.
    """
    csv_file = open("{}s like list.csv".format(username), 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
    csv_file.write("Track Title, Track URL\n")  # Writes headers to CSV file.
    offset_number = 0
    complete = False
    while number_of_user_likes > 0 and complete is False:
        if offset_number < number_of_user_likes:
            try:
                track_fetch = urllib.request.urlopen(
                    "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{}/favorites.json?client_id="
                    "********************************&offset={}&limit1".format(user.id, offset_number)).read()
                track_data = json.loads(track_fetch.decode())
                if "," in track_data[0]["title"]:
                    track_title = track_data[0]["title"].replace(",",
                                                                 "")  # Removes commas as causes issues with .csv files
                else:
                    track_title = track_data[0]["title"]
                csv_file.write("{},{}\n".format(track_title, track_data[0]["permalink_url"]))
                offset_number += 1
                print("{} of {} ({}%)".format(offset_number, number_of_user_likes,
                                              round(float(100 / number_of_user_likes * offset_number), 2)))
            except IndexError:
                print("There is an issue with Soundcloud, please try again")
            except requests.HTTPError:
                print("There is an issue with Soundcloud, please try again")
            except requests.ConnectionError:
                print("Check your internet connection")
        else:
            complete = True
            finished()


def finished():
    """
    Runs after the users like list has finished being saved.
    """
    print("Finished")


get_username()
```

Answer (score 5):

### Use of functions

Functions can return values.  You should do that instead of passing back results indirectly via global variables.

In `get_username()`, `user_id = (valid_username(username))` is nonsense, since the `valid_username()` function never returns anything.

Worse, you are misusing functions as if they were goto labels.  `get_username()` and `valid_username()` are mutually recursive, which is inappropriate.  Furthermore, `get_username()` triggers *all* of the activity in the program, which is much more than getting the username as the function name would suggest.

Rearranging everything…

```
def prompt_username():
    return input("Please enter your Soundcloud username: ")

def get_account(username):
    try:
        return client.get("/resolve", url="http://soundcloud.com/{}/".format(username))
    except requests.HTTPError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid username")

def prompt_account():
    while True:
        try:
            return get_account(prompt_username())
        except ValueError:
            print("The username you entered is invalid.  Please try again")

def get_favorites(account):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{}.json?consumer_key={}",
                                 account.id, consumer_key)
    …
    return decoded_user_info['username']

def save_favorites(account, favorites):
    …
```

Now you can write this, which *does* convey what the program does, unlike your `get_username()` "function" which was really just a goto label:

```
account = prompt_account()
save_favorites(account, get_favorites(account))
```

Answer (score 2):

- First of all I would use a class for this, handling variables between functions using `globals` is very ugly and hard to maintain. Using a class we can easily share attributes across all of its methods easily and cleanly.
- `user_id = (valid_username(username))` is actually useless as you're not returning anything from that function.
- To shorten our urls we can create a global variable:

```
   API_BASE_URL = "https://api.soundcloud.com"
```

- As you are importing the `requests` library why not use its `.get()` method as well instead of `urllib.request.urlopen`. Another advantage here is that the Response object returned here has a [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) method that returns a dict to us. So, code will simplify to:

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    decode_user_info = r.json()
```

- For creating a csv file better use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module instead of writing lines with `,` and also you are removing commas from track titles to make your workaround work.
- For handling files always use the `with` statement, it makes sure the file is closed properly in case an error occurs.
- Instead of using `while number_of_user_likes > 0 and complete is False: if offset_number < number_of_user_likes:...`, you can use a simple for-loop with [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
    for offset_number in range(self.number_of_likes):
```

**Complete code:**

```
import csv
import soundcloud
import urllib.request
import requests


CLIENT_ID = "*******************************"
CLIENT_SECRET = "******************************"
API_BASE_URL = "https://api.soundcloud.com"


class Client:

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret):
        self.client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=client_id,
                                        client_secret=client_secret)
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.username = self.get_username()
        self.user_info()
        self.save_likes()

    def get_username(self):
        """
        Asks user for their Soundcloud username.
        """
        username = input("Please enter your Soundcloud username: ")
        return self.validate_username(username)

    def validate_username(self, username):
        """
        Checks if supplied username is valid.
        """
        try:
            self.user = self.client.get("/resolve", url="http://soundcloud.com/{}/".format(username))
            return username
        except requests.HTTPError:  # Runs if account cannot be found.
            print("The username you entered is invalid, please try again")
            return self.get_username()

    def user_info(self):
        """
        Retrieves the users information from their user ID
        and prints the number of tracks they have liked.
        """
        r = requests.get("{}/users/{}.json?client_id={}".format(API_BASE_URL,
                                                                self.user.id,
                                                                self.client_id))

        decode_user_info = r.json()
        self.number_of_likes = decode_user_info['public_favorites_count']
        print("You have liked a total of {} tracks".format(self.number_of_likes))

    def save_likes(self):
        """
        Creates a CSV file with headers and then saves the users likes to the CSV file.
        """
        with open("{}s like list.csv".format(self.username), 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["Track Title", "Track URL"])  # Writes headers to CSV file.
            for offset_number in range(self.number_of_likes):
                try:
                    r = requests.get("{}/users/{}/favorites.json?client_id={}&offset={}&limit=1".format(API_BASE_URL,
                                                                                                        self.user.id,
                                                                                                        self.client_id,
                                                                                                        offset_number))
                    track_data = r.json()[0]
                    writer.writerow([track_data['title'], track_data['permalink_url']])
                    print("{} of {} ({}%)".format(offset_number+1, self.number_of_likes,
                                                  round(float(100 / self.number_of_likes * offset_number), 2)))
                except IndexError:
                    print("There is an issue with Soundcloud, please try again")
                except requests.HTTPError:
                    print("There is an issue with Soundcloud, please try again")
                except requests.ConnectionError:
                    print("Check your internet connection")
        self.finished()

    def finished(self):
        """
        Runs after the users like list has finished being saved.
        """
        print("Finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
```

Answer (score 2):

### CSV support

Python has a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library.  Use it.  It handles some issues for you automatically, such as the quoting of special characters.

### Ineffective use of the SoundCloud API client

There should be no reason to resort to using the `requests` library when you're already using an API client that is built for the task.  You don't have to worry about HTTP or JSON.  It's as simple as this:

```
import csv
import soundcloud
import requests

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=CLIENT)

def write_like_list(username, file):
    try:
        favorites = client.get('/users/{}/favorites'.format(username))
        csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
        csv_writer.writerow(['Track Title', 'Track URL'])
        for fav in favorites:
            csv_writer.writerow([fav.title, fav.permalink_url])
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        if 404 == e.response.status_code:
            raise ValueError("User not found: {}".format(username))
        else:
            raise  # Some other error.  Propagate the exception

username = …
with open('{}s like list.csv'.format(username), 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    write_like_list(username, file)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that Python 2's native CSV library isn't Unicode aware - there's a block of code at the end of https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples which you can use.

Comment: Thank you, I will make the changes, thanks for the feedback!